# Getting user's current time (not server or computer clock BUT ACTUAL real time) and pass as a variable into php

Tags: php

How can I do this?

EDIT: I'm not sure if this would work but sometimes you get those annoying pop-ups that tell you what city/suburb you're in (usually for dating sites) - could we somehow extrapolate from that data what the time is?  Is this data based on a reverse IP lookup?

Any suggestion code to get me started (I don't really know what I'm looking for - just the end result I want) would be fantastic!

Thanks.

Comment: you should be more specific on what "Real Time" is for you ... because afaik you will need either a user input or a 3rd party code to grab (for example a small javascript) anything from the user's computer as php has no power over it ... but since you said not the server time nor the windows clock time it makes me wonder what "Real Time" is for you...

Comment: You'll need to capture some Time Fairies in a bottle.

Comment: You totatlly want to read Evil Pigeon's answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Geo Location API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) to get the user's location, then lookup their local time via some web service like [this](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm).

Realise that you have to rely on the time kept on a server somewhere. If your server has the local time to a reasonable degree of accuracy, you could just offset your server's time to match the user's time-zone.

Comment: By the way, I think only Opera (and Firefox through a plugin) support the geolocation api. EDIT: maybe chrome 5 too.

Comment: Hmm, other than that you'd have to rely on a less reliable service such as GeoIP or user input. Many sites allow users to configure a time zone in their profile. If you're looking at giving each user a login, this would be ideal.

Comment: Sounds like a plan ... smell like plan ... deserve cookies !

Comment: Note, GeoIP services are inaccurate, and worse, users are sometimes behind proxies that may be hundreds of miles away, or further.  Some of the most active IPs in the logs of a site I maintain turned out to be a pool of proxies for a major satellite internet company.  Using GeoIP to guess timezone isn't a terrible idea, but it's best to let your users override it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - will make sure to have a user override.

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript, dateObject.getTimezoneOffset() can return the offset between the users local time and the GMT in minutes.

Comment: Thanks but will this get the user's computer's time though or the physical time in that location???

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this service [EarthTools](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone) They provide a service that can return the time of the user on the basis of longitude and latitude.For getting Longitude and latitude you can use another service [Smart IP](http://smart-ip.net/geoip-api).

**Note:** Although these services can provide you data but still its not reliable because user may have used proxy servers to access the web so in that way the result will be not valid.

Answer (score -1):

First:
`session_start()` in the php pages

then I would create a small javascript in the bottom of each page that gets the time

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['browsertime'])) { 
?>
document.write('<img src="image.php?time="+browsertime+"&type=.jpg">');
<?php
}
```

and in the image.php

`$_SESSION['browsertime']=$_GET['browsertime'];`

with some extra checks, of course...